# How to overcome from a security breach in Jwt tocken validation

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I have used jwt token securing angular application and in the backend, we have used asp.net core API. After login successfully we have saved the token in local storage in web browser memory and we log out from the application simply remove the token from browser memory.

We can stop the user to access the application through the application but if some have the token he can access the endpoint using postman and other api test tool. How can we overcome this problem.Is there any way to remove the token or expire the token manually.

Comment: Use refresh tokens like [here](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/05/30/refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-web-api/)

Comment: What Jabberwocky said. Short access token times (~5-10 minutes), long living refresh tokens (which can be revoked) and invalidated server-sided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revoke the jwt token is not easy , there is no standard way to revoke access tokens unless the Authorization Server implements custom logic which forces you to store generated access token in database and do database checks with each request.

A simply way is using short lived access tokens and refresh token , use refresh token to renew the access token , if you want to revoke the user , revoke the refresh token on server side , clear refresh token and access token on client side .

Another way is reference tokens. The basic idea is Authorization Server will store the contents of the token in a data store and will only issue a unique identifier for this token back to the client. The API receiving this reference must then open a back-channel communication to Authorization Server to validate the token , so that the server side could control whether reference token(unique identifier) is still available . Identity server 4 also provides the reference token feature :

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html